# Sails.js; sails-migrations in production AWS, getting ERCONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, sails.js, database-migration

Attempting:

```
sails-migrations --env production migrate
```

Returns:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
```

We're running MySQL on all IP addresses under port 3308, and using a domain socket file.

Here is the relative preferred production environment config:

```
  connections: {
    prodMysqlServer: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      user: 'thisuser',
      password: 'thispass',
      database: 'thisdb',
      socketPath: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
    }
  },    
  models: {
     connection: 'prodMysqlServer'
  },
```

But, this config fails as well:

```
  connections: {
    prodMysqlServer: {
      adapter: 'sails-mysql',
      user: 'thisuser',
      password: 'thispass',
      host: 'stage1', // resolves
      port: 3308,
      database: 'thisdb'
    }
  },    
  models: {
     connection: 'prodMysqlServer'
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the sails-migrations application.  Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations/issues/68